# How to change identical operators in Python list of strings by including different numbers or subscripts?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings in Python, containing alphabets and operators as follows:

```
['a', '+', 'b', 'd', '+', 'e', 'g', '*', 'h', '/', '-', '/'].
```

I am trying to use Python to rename the first `'+'` as potentially `'+1'` (where the `'1'` next to `'+'` could be a subscript) and the second `'+'` as `'+2'` to distinguish between the two '+' operators. And so on for the other operators as well. Also, for similar other bigger examples containing multiple `'+'`, `'-'`, `'*'`, `'/'`, `'<'`, `'>'`, etc.

For example, in the above list of strings, the modification would result to the desired output I wish to achieve:

```
['a', '+1', 'b', 'd', '+2', 'e', 'g', '*1', 'h', '/1', '-1', '/2'].
```

I was trying to use a `for` loop to find each operator and replace it by the numbers, but haven't been successful. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does your `for` loop look like? You can start with looping through each string in  the list, and using a dictionary to store a counter to track how many `'+'` or `'*'` or other operators you've seen so far, and just add that counter value to your string. Also, do you you know how to format a string such that you can insert a `1` into a `'+'` to make it `'+1'` ?

Answer (score 3):

We can use a dictionary to store the current amount of special characters in your code:

```
specChars = {'+':0, '-':0, '*':0, '/':0, '<':0, '>':0}
```

Now, we can iterate through your list and update the elements appropriately:

```
specChars = {'+':0, '-':0, '*':0, '/':0, '<':0, '>':0}

lst = ['a', '+', 'b', 'd', '+', 'e', 'g', '*', 'h', '/', '-', '/']

for i in range(len(lst)):
  if lst[i] in specChars:
    specChars[lst[i]] += 1
    lst[i] = lst[i] + str(specChars[lst[i]])

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['a', '+1', 'b', 'd', '+2', 'e', 'g', '*1', 'h', '/1', '-1', '/2']
```

This loop works by iterating through our list of characters, `lst`. If the character is a special character, we increase the corresponding value in `specChars`. Then, we concatenate the frequency of that character.

I hope this helped! Please let me know if you need any further clarifications or details :)

Comment: nice one... yours is more efficient than mine :-)

Comment: You can also use [`for idx, item in enumerate(lst)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of `for i in range(len(lst))`. That way you have access to the item index _and_ the item itself within the loop.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```py
def fun(arr):
    operator = {
    '+': 1,
    '-': 1,
    '*': 1,
    '/': 1,
    '<': 1,
    '>': 1
    }

    res = []

    for i in arr:
        if i in operator:
            res.append(i + str(operator[i]))
            operator[i] += 1
        else:
            res.append(i)

    return res

print(fun(['a', '+', 'b', 'd', '+', 'e', 'g', '*', 'h', '/', '-', '/']))
```